# Is there a way to implement a __post_init__ method for inherited classes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, decorator, python-decorators, metaclass

I would like to prevent a user of an instance mistakenly creating a non existing attribute when using said object.

Say I have a class with an init and some attributes :

```
class Foo(obj):
   def __init__(self, a, b):
       self.a = a
       self.b = b
```

I would like to enable setting existing attributes while preventing the creation of a new attribute:

```
myobj = foo(1,2)
>> 
print(myobj.a)
>> 1
myobj.a = 2
myobj.c = 1
>> AttributeError: frozen instance
```

That is fairly easy with `__setattr__` override and a boolean :

```
class Foo(obj):
   _is_frozen = False
   def __init__(self, a, b):
       self.a = a
       self.b = b
       self._is_frozen = True
 
   def __setattr__(self, name, value):
       if not self._is_frozen or hasattr(self, name):
           super().__setattr__(name, value)
       else:
           raise AttributeError("frozen instance")
```

Now the step I struggle with is when a new class inherits Foo. If new attributes must be defined after the call to the `super().__init__()`, the instance is frozen.

I have tried using decorator to make a metaclass but the decorator of the mother class is still called at the `super().__init__()` call and I can't define my new attributes.

In other words, is there a way to make a kind of `__post_init__` method (reference to the dataclass module) that would only be called after all inits (the one of the class and the ones of the inherited classes) have been called ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indeed - that is tricky.

Having a decorator on the `__init__` of base class that would freeze the instance after `__init__`, as you mentioned have the problem of state  -  it is possible to add other state variables, or count the  `__init__` depth, and use a metaclass (or `__init_subclass__`) to decorate all `__init__` method in the subclasses, so that it would do the freezing only when exiting the outermost `__init__`.

But there is an easier way using metaclasses: the metaclass' `__call__` method is what calls a class `__new__` and then `__init__` when creating a new instance. So, it suffices to put code to calling a `__post_init__` on  a custom metaclass' `__call__` (or freeze the instance directly from it)

```
class PostInitMeta(type):
    def __call__(cls, *args, **kw):
        instance = super().__call__(*args, **kw)  # < runs __new__ and __init__
        instance.__post_init__()  
        return instance
    
class Freezing(metaclass=PostInitMeta):
    _frozen = False
    def __post_init__(self):
        self._frozen = True
        
    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        if self._frozen:
            raise AttributeError() # or do nothing, and return as you prefer
        super().__setattr__(name, value)
        
class A(Freezing):
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
        
class B(A):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        super().__init__(a)
        self.b = b
```

And testing this in interactive mode:

```
In [18]: b = B(2, 3)

In [19]: b.a
Out[19]: 2

In [20]: b.b
Out[20]: 3

In [21]: b.b = 5
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [21], line 1
----> 1 b.b = 5
```

Comment: Works like a charm ! Thank you so much ! I didn't know `__call__` was the encapulating method of `__new__` and `__init__`.

Answer (score 2):

There is a simpler solution using `__slots__`.
`__slots__` basically freezes the instance (-specific) attributes.

Note: There are some use-cases which may prohibit the use of `__slots__`, check [Using Slots](https://wiki.python.org/moin/UsingSlots).

```
class Foo:
    __slots__ = ['a', 'b']
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

foo = Foo(1,2)
# foo.c = 3 # => attribute error - 'Foo' object has no attribute 'c'

class Bar(Foo):
    __slots__ = ['c']
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        super().__init__(a, b)
        self.c = 3

bar = Bar(1,2,3)
# bar.d = 4 # => attribute error - 'Bar' object has no attribute 'd'
```

#### Explanation

Without `__slots__`, `__dict__` is used by default which is of type `dict`.
`__dict__` contains the data stored in the program's memory *for a specific object*.

Since it's possible to add keys to a `dict` simply by doing `__dict__[key] = value`, this allows for adding instance attributes whenever we want (by writing `foo.c = 3` which translates to `foo.__dict__['c'] = 3`).

By using `__slots__`, and using a `non-dict` for it, we stop that from happening.

On top of that, `__slots__` also provides memory optimization.